# how to correctly format values coming from a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
foreach (var book in query)
{
   Response.Write(book.Title);
   foreach (var author in book.Authors)
   {
      Response.Write(" , "+author.FirstName +" "+ author.MiddleInitial + 
         " "+  author.LastName );
   }
}
```

Right now I am printing the Book Title : All author names with a ",".

I would like print : (If they have more than one author separate each author with a  "," (done) and add "AND" to the last author name - If they don't have more than one author no ", is required.

How can I do that??

Comment: This appears to be homework. Please let us know what you've tried,  how you think you should approach the problem and we'll be happy to help. We will not just do your homework for you, however.

Comment: _"How to correctly ... "_ - by __not__ using `Response.Write()`

Comment: @Randolpho : "We will not just do your homework for you" - turns out to be wrong...

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I realized after the fact that this was a homework type question. Can we modify that to "we won't do your homework for you anymore?" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better of building the string first, and then writing it to the screen outside of the loop. I would suggest using a `StringBuilder` for this.

To use the `StringBuilder` class, you'll need to import the `System.Text` namespace:

```
using System.Text;
```

And here is some sample code to demonstrate:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var author in book.Authors)
{
    //if the string already contains data append a comma
    if (builder.Length > 0)
        builder.Append(", ");

    //append the author to the string
    builder.AppendFormat("{0} {1} {2}", author.FirstName, author.MiddleInitial, author.LastName);
}

Response.Write(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: Builder.Length will always be 0 here.

Comment: I don't think so. It will only be 0 on the first run through the loop. After the first author is appended, on the next iteration `builder.Length` will be greater than zero.

Comment: Where is the relationship between author and the builder? When I added the above code the builder is not printing any names at all.

Comment: Look at the `builder.AppendFormat` line. It's just using a format string to concatenate the author's name.

Comment: Yes I did see that but how is builder.length going to be  > 0 if you look at the code you just declared builder and used it inside the foreach loop. I am not getting any author names printed using the above code. I have to see if I can add something like builder.length = book.authors.count or something.

Comment: Because `builder` is declared outside of the loop. On the first iteration, the builder will be empty, but on the second iteration it won't be empty anymore.

Comment: I added a breakpoint and added watch it is always coming as 0. It is not printing any names.  I will update you if I am able to get it working. Thank you so much.

Comment: There's something you're missing, because this code will definitely work. Double check to make sure that you're not missing something. Good luck ;)

Comment: I am able to print the values by if (book.Authors.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                Response.Write("****:" + book.Authors.Count());

                                Response.Write(author.FirstName + " " + author.MiddleInitial + " " + author.LastName + ", ");

                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }

Answer (score 1):

Use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) to combine strings with a separator.

```
var authors = string.Join(", ", book.Authors.Select(author=>string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", author.FirstName, author.MiddleInitial, author.LastName)));
Response.Write(authors);
```